# Reading JSON file from azure Container to Data Bricks as Dictionary

Tags: python, json, dataframe, pyspark, databricks

I have a prefect JSON file in Azure container as the file is created using python dictionary, I can see the file with the help of dbutils and even read it by head but head can't read the whole file.

Using `spark.read.json(file_path)` reads JSON formated file as dataframe and throws error courrpt corrupt.

How i can get this file as Dictionary in Databricks ?

Comment: Are you sure the json in "prefect", or you think it? check it with an online json validator.

Comment: yes i did , also this file is created using python dictionary

Comment: Than you should post it as well as the complete stacktrace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just simple open command works for this issue, just have to be careful with
json load and loads

```
json_path = './config/jsonfile.json'
jsonData = open(json_path)
dictionaryObj = json.load(jsonData)
```